# Can't find my profile id number

Tags: facebook, build

I am trying to build an app and it is asking for my profile id number. Because I have a customized Facebook profile, it hides the id number and the app will not take jccalloway59. I have been trying to do this for two days now. How in the hell do I find my id number?!?

Comment: I have built more than 70 apps, and never asked the Facebook my profilID. Are you sure? Could you post the url, where you try to create that app?

Answer (score 6):

You can get it at `https://graph.facebook.com/jccalloway59`.
 
For an arbitrary user, replace `jccalloway59` with the username.

Answer (score 4):

Get it from the graph API explorer tool

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me

Answer (score -1):

So, if some of ur photos, ull find at the url: fbid=8823792739123 ...there is

ie: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?**fbid=29152428753XXXX**&set=a...

or  https://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME.